# How to read video file from directory to use file name into program

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read video file from the directory which might be in .MOV, mp4 ect. then convert it into audio file. When i giving manual input to the video file name it working correctly, but i want my code to read it from directory which contain only one video file.

```
 for vid in glob.glob('/home/qwickbit/Desktop/Qwickbit/Tennis_OpenCV/*.MOV'):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
    ret, video = cap.read()
#   video = input ("Inter the Input Video File Name:")
    minLength = 50
    minBF = 1
    audio =    "Audio_file%d%d.wav" % (minLength,minBF)
    audio_convert = "ffmpeg -i {video} -ac 1  -f wav -vn {audio}".format(video=video, audio= audio)
    subprocess.call(audio_convert,shell=True)
```

Comment: Can you post the error. The code looks fine to me.

Comment: for vid in glob.glob('/home/qwickbit/Desktop/Qwickbit/Tennis_OpenCV/*.MOV'):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
ret, video = cap.read()

minLength = 50
minBF = 1
audio =    "Audio_file%d%d.wav" % (minLength,minBF)
audio_convert = "ffmpeg -i {video} -ac 1  -f wav -vn {audio}".format(video=video, audio= audio)
subprocess.call(audio_convert,shell=True)
return audio

Comment: I am not getting any error but it not giving me any output. when i use video = input() then it gives output in wave file, the glob.glob are not reading video file

Comment: i have done some change in my code. please see

Comment: You are sure that the file really exists in `'/home/qwickbit/Desktop/Qwickbit/Tennis_OpenCV/'`? They files have the suffix .MOV and not .mov or other file format like .mpeg.